# Click every label onload ChartJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to click every label after the chart is loaded using a ChartJS chart. I've written the following code and am having trouble getting past what I've got. Any insight or help would be appreciated.

```
        myChart.legend.legendItems.forEach(function(label, key) {
            console.log(myChart.legend.legendItems[key].hidden);
            if (label.datasetIndex) {
                myChart.legend.legendItems[key].hidden = true;
            }
            console.log(myChart.legend.legendItems[key].hidden);
        });

        myChart.update();
```

I'm trying to draw the chart so that when it first loads, every label is crossed out and hidden. DO I have the right idea setting it to hidden and updating? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
 multiLineChart.legend.legendItems[0].hidden = true;
 multiLineChart.data.datasets[0].hidden = true;
```

For some reason the update method didn't quite work, but this did:

```
function init() {
 myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: chartType,
  data: data,
  options: options
 });
myBarChart.legend.legendItems[0].hidden = true;
myBarChart.data.datasets[0].hidden = true;
}
```

And your function:

```
multiLineChart.legend.legendItems.forEach(function(label, key) {
  multiLineChart.legend.legendItems[key].hidden = true;
  multiLineChart.data.datasets[key].hidden = true;
});
```

Result:
[image]

Codepen: [Chart.js Pre Crossed Series](http://codepen.io/k3no/pen/bwzVbN?editors=0011)